# Exclude a directory when building python .whl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

Given a Python code base with 3 subdirectories: common, private, public, how do I build a Python wheel file that excludes one of the directories?

Specifically, I want to build a wheel file that includes `common` and `public` but excludes `private`

I have following setup:

```
mypackage/
    mylib/
        common/
            __init__.py
           ... common code ...
        private/
            __init__.py
            ... private code ...
        public/
            __init__.py
            ... public code ...
    setup_public.py
    setup_private.py
```

My `setup_public.py` looks like this:

```
imoprt setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="public",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="james",
    description="public pkg",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=("mylib/private",)), 
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ],
)
```

When I build the package and install it:

```
python3 setup_public.py sdist bdist_wheel
pip3 install dist/public-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

And then check to verify the public directory is excluded, I find it is still there:

```
python3

# works, as expected
>>> import mylib.public 

# also works, unexpected! i do not want to expose this code
>>> import mylib.private
```

Separating the code into 3 distinct packages isn't an option here for technical reasons, so I am seeking a solution that will let me configure setuptools to ignore a folder.

Comment: Can't you put private outside of `mylib`? Either you import from it into public and common, in which case you'll need it in the wheel, or you don't in which cae why is it in mylib?

Comment: @Dan because I am shipping code to two different audiences. And the public audience cannot have the private code. This is a very minified and simplified example, the actual code base is large. Another alternative would be to decouple the common code into it's own package, but that isn't feasible right now. So I want a file path exclusion solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple mistake in the setup script, this line:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=("mylib/private",)),
```

Should be:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=("mylib.private",)),
```

i.e. excluding the package name, not the filesystem path.

Comment: This does not work, I am still able to import `mylib.private`. In case it was due to something getting cached, I made sure to rebuild it completely clean. No luck.

Comment: It does work, I have verified it by recreating your directory tree and building a package locally. Make sure that you are not simply importing `mylib.private` from the current working directory, by checking that the `mylib.public.__file__` is actually the *installed* code in `site-packages`. Note that I needed to add an empty `mylib/__init__.py` file when packaging your code, it was missing in the question (in which case, `find_packages` would not have found *any* packages).

Comment: it it indeed working for me now, i must have made a mistake before